# find date and time coming in between two given date and time that increment by 5 minutes

Tags: java, date, datetime

JAVA | How to find date and time coming in between two given date and time that increment by 5 minutes?

For example,  if the starting point is   [29/1/2017  5:40:00 AM]

And the stopping point is                [29/1/2017  6:00:00 AM]

The list (based on starting and  stopping points ) and it is must be like this

```
29/1/2017  5:40:00 AM                                                                     
29/1/2017  5:45:00 AM    
29/1/2017  5:50:00 AM     
29/1/2017  5:55:00 AM     
29/1/2017  6:00:00 AM
```

Please don’t use JODA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres the Java8 Version using the new DateTime API. If you're on Java8 you should use this code.

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/u h:m:s a");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("29/1/2017 5:40:00 AM", dateTimeFormatter);
LocalDateTime endDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("29/1/2017 6:00:00 AM", dateTimeFormatter);

for(; !dateTime.isAfter(endDateTime); dateTime = dateTime.plusMinutes(5))
    System.out.println(dateTime.format(dateTimeFormatter));
```

Comment: This new Java 8 styling looks cool!!

Comment: I agree. Will take some time to get used to it, but it saves code and it's finally immutable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not interested in using `JODA`, you can achieve this using `java.util.Calendar`.
Say, you have two `String` objects representing two dates:

```
String startDateStr = "29/1/2017 5:40:00 AM";
String endDateStr = "29/1/2017 6:00:00 AM";
```

Create a `DateFormat` to parse these:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
```

Now, create two `java.util.Date` objects and two `java.util.Calendar` instances representing the dates:

```
Date startDate = dateFormat.parse(startDateStr);
Date endDate = dateFormat.parse(endDateStr);

Calendar startDateCal = Calendar.getInstance();
startDateCal.setTime(startDate);

Calendar endDateCal = Calendar.getInstance();
endDateCal.setTime(endDate);
```

Now, you can iterate through the dates like shown below:

```
for(Date d = startDateCal.getTime(); startDateCal.before(endDateCal); startDateCal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5)){
    d = startDateCal.getTime();
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(d.getTime()));
}
```

I thing, this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thank you , this is exactly what I need

Comment: FYI, the old [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) classes are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system). Supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.